# How to open a file without using openfiledialog in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 to develop a windows form application using c++.

I want to open a text file without the user browsing through the directory to select the required file, that is without using OpenFileDialog tool.

In short
If the user click a button named "Open File" in the form, a file should open rather than a Dialog

[image]

[image]

Comment: Opened in notepad.exe?

Comment: Or simply use `std::ifstream`

Comment: @basile-starynkevitch, Sorry that my initial post was not conveying the problem I was facing. I have edited my post to give a more clearer view

Comment: Of the topic--is there any particular reason my question is voted down. I am new to stackoverflow, so any suggestions or reasons anyone provide will be helpful??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ShellExecute` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to do what you're trying to do.

For example, to open a Word document at the location `C:\SomeDirectory\MyWord.docx`, you could call the following function:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\SomeDirectory\\MyWord.docx", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

This will attempt to open the file using the default application associated with its file extension (e.g., Microsoft Word, in the above example; possibly Notepad.exe for text files; etc.).